# create lookup table from all formats

Tags: sas

I would like to export all available `user defined formats` into a single lookup table that would contain columns `format`, `value`, and `label` (so that I can use it to manipulate data in `R` and `SQL`).

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: [Proc format](https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug01/cc/cc4021.pdf) would be a good place to start

Comment: I don't want to build a format, I want to create a lookup table

Comment: Read up on the cntlout option.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will work if I run `PROC FORMAT LIBRARY=lib_name CNTLOUT=psn_libname (KEEP=FMTNAME START END LABEL); RUN;` for all libraries and concatenate the results

Comment: Comments are not for answering the question, but are intended to clarify the question.  Answers are where the answers go. :)

Comment: I was writing it, sorry for the almost duplicate, I'd raher choose mine though as it's a bit more detailed.

Comment: downvoter I'll gladly improve my post if you care to explain why it deserves negative points

Comment: It is  more detailed, but that's because it includes details that were not in your original question that no one here could possibly know.

Comment: In my view it is in the question as I say I want all user defined formats, so if the solution is library specific it's relevant to include a way to explore libraries. But fair enough, and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the contents of a SAS format catalog (commonly, `formats.sas7bcat`) with the [`CNTLOUT` method on PROC FORMAT:](http://support.sas.com/kb/22/194.html)

```
proc format lib=mylib cntlout=myformatds;
quit;
```

This would take the default format catalog stored in the library `mylib` as `formats.sas7bcat` and export it to a dataset, `myformatds` in the `work` library.

Answer (score 0):

As @user667489 indicated in the comment, the answer was in using `PROC FORMAT` with the `CNTLOUT` option.

The general format of the instruction is:

```
PROC FORMAT
LIBRARY=lib_name CNTLOUT=created_table;
RUN;
```

One must specify the library however, to find out which library is relevant one can take a look at `SASHELP.VFORMAT`.
Then one can create different tables and concatenate them.

In my case all user defined formats were in a library called `LIBRARY` and I don't need all columns so my solution is:

```
PROC FORMAT
LIBRARY=LIBRARY CNTLOUT=FORMAT_LOOKUP (KEEP=FMTNAME START END LABEL);
RUN;
```